# LED PWM with FOD8342 Optocoupler

Tags: pwm, led-driver, isolated

I'm trying to PWM some high power LEDs from a isolated control line using a FOD8342. It worked on the bench when prototyping, but now it's part of the final design it seems to work for a minute then blows up the FOD8342. It may have been when prototyping I didn't test it enough....just proved it worked then moved on.

I'm not sure if the FOD8342 is designed to do low sided switching like this. The [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FOD8342-D.PDF) figure 23 seems to imply it is? I'm not really sure though.

In use it'll have a 400Hz PWM signal controlling it, but for testing I've been manually switching the control lines. Currently replaced the FOD8342 twice.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've checked the build and manufacturing seems to be inline with the design which makes me think the concept is wrong.

[image: Isolated PWM Circuit]

Comment: You need to supply a link to the LED data sheet and maybe specify what current limiting regime it uses.

Comment: I don't fully know what the LEDs are yet, I'm just using a 300R-ish resistor as a load.

Comment: You need to show the test circuit that is causing the problems. A 300 ohm load is less than 100 mA and you show 1 amp on the diagram.

Comment: This is NOT how to design a constant current limited switch driving a diode. the emitter resistor reduces voltage gain and thus makes the output-current input-voltage-controlled. Move Re to Rc and recompute value. for a nominal 13mA recommended drive current

Comment: This push-pull driver does not consume more than 6mA  while your load is 24V/0.3k = 80mA The problem is you are not saturating the driver because your input current is gain is too low. as stated above. so the thermal problem is 80mA with some voltage across the IGBT. Fix the input stage common emitter to drive between the recommended range for the IR LED. I suggested 13mA which is mean of 10 to 16mA. you are lucky to get more than 3 mA less than 4

Comment: Going on what Tony above says, what is the peak voltage of LED_PWM_CTRL?

Comment: The PWM input control voltage is progrmamable from 0-10V peak. It was intended to run from 10V.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This push-pull driver does not consume more than 6mA while your load is 24V+/0.3k = approx 70mA. The problem is you are not saturating the U10 driver because your input Q1 current is voltage gain is too low. as stated above.

So if the output draws current from a resistor unlike a MOSFET or IGBT AND the output voltage is not saturated, the tiny chip dissipates excessive power.

### Design error

Fix the input stage common emitter to drive between the recommended range for the IR LED. I suggested 13mA which is mean of 10 to 16mA. you are lucky to get more than 3 mA less than 4 .

### Test Simulation error

Then replace 180 Ohm load with a 1nF capacitor to simulate IGBT (or improved model so you do not have steady state power dissipation... just on edges.

Comment: I think maybe I need to change the 180R to 260R at the collector and the base resistor to 7.5K to get 16mA through the FOD8342 diode, which has a 0.8V forward  voltage from 5V supply? hFE of transistor is 140?

Comment: IR diode Vf= 1.5V@ 10mA +0.3/-0.4 with -1.8mV/‘C which is the minimum recommended current. @ 16mA it will be higher due to Ri internal.not lower =0.8V.  Which is the minimum VFHL an output voltage with hysteresis and Io = 0mA

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm even more confused now. Fig 21 shows a Vf of 1.5V at If of 16mA? So collector resistor would need to be 5V-1.5V = 3.5V / 16mA = 218R?  Base resistor would be aprox 0.2x218R*140(hFE) = 6.1K ?   I appreciate you're help, but just new to this.

Comment: The control variable is @ 10mA not Vf. The reading in Fig21 @ 25'C  = 1.425V (est. of ¼ of 0.1V grid)   All graphs are  Nominal and spec is above....1.1. to 1.8V@ 25'C @ 10mA so use nominal for computing R value yet you know there is  self heating (2 burnt chips)  ,so  compensate. for temp rise so lower Vf or target for higher current 16mA at 25'C. If you have a wide ambient spec. then you need a better design with CC regulator. transistor

Comment: if   Ic=13mA Vce=0, Vf=1.45, Vcc=5.0 then R= (5-1.45)/13mA=273 Ohms. With emitter grounded  and hFE saturated only 10% of linear hFE or Ic/ib=10 whichever is better, Rb is about 10x 273 roughly. You can never use hFE when saturated as current gain drops like a rock below Vce=1V (depending on Ic)

Answer (score 1):

**This is a gate driver IC, it is intended for high peak current but not high average current.**

According to the datasheet, at 1A the output voltage drop will be 1-1.5V:

[image]

This means the chip will dissipate 1-1.5W at 100% duty cycle, which is much above the maximum rating. Even at 50% duty cycle it will blow the chip since it has a maximum dissipation of 500mW under ideal conditions.

Also, as Tony says, your driving circuit is wrong. You need to fix it as per Tony's answer to ensure the diode inside FOD8342 receives 10mA current as per datasheet spec. But even if you fix this, that won't change the fact that this chip can't drive 1A continuously.

Solution: use your isolated gate driver to drive the gate of a MOSFET which will switch the high current. Since 28V will probably exceed the FET max Vgs rating, you will need to supply the gate driver with a voltage like 12V (from a linear regulator powered by your 28V supply).

Note the symbol in your question is wrong. FOD8342 uses FET output devices, not BJTs:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for sounding slow, but what does "at 1A the output voltage drop will be 1-1.5V" actually mean? VO will be 1.5V above VSS?

Also, how did you work out 1-1.5V converts to 1-1.5W?

Comment: The output devices inside the chip are MOSFETs, so when they are ON, they behave like resistors. According to the graph "output low voltage versus output low current" indeed VO will be 1.5V above VSS with 1A current, and this voltage drop occurs in the MOSFET inside the chip. Then, P = I*V.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Fortunatly I've done some more investigation and the actual load is 300mA so hopefully will be within max power disipation.